# Is the relation {(1,1),(1,2)} transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

For it to be transitive (1,2) would need to exist in the relation.
And it does, because a and b happen to be the same number.
But sets don't contain duplicates, so it either is transitive, or it cant be transitive if a and b are the same value.

Comment: Why would the set need to contain duplicates? Transitivity only insists that $(1,2)$ (and, indeed $(1,1)$, if $a=b=c=1$) are in the set, not that they are in the set twice!

Comment: My confusion started with this video. https://youtu.be/LLHrSc4g0ZM?t=680
Where she says 1,1 and 1,2 require 1,2 to be in the set to be transitive. She says it isn't and moves on.

Comment: @naveendankal: Does not seem to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Grimchester: There is indeed a mistake in the video.

Comment: Yes I agree on the second look at both the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relation is transitive if whenever a~b and b~c we have a~c.

So when do we have both a~b and b~c?

Well, the only relations we have are 1~1 and 1~2.  So if b~c then we must have b=1.  So then we have a~1, which must mean that a=1.  So the only two cases to check are $a=b=c=1$ and $a = b = 1$, $c=2$.  That is:

- Since 1~1 and 1~1, we must have 1~1 if the relation is transitive.
- Since 1~1 and 1~2, we must have 1~2 if the relation is transitive.

Both of these hold, so the relation is indeed transitive.

Comment: What about this: {(1,3),(1, 2),(2, 3),(2, 2)} .. it's transitive for (1,2)-(2,3) cause (1,3) exists. But  (1,2)-(2,2) requires (1,2) to exist and it doesn't.

So is the relation then not transitive, because it fails in 1 instance?

Comment: "But (1,2)-(2,2) requires (1,2) to exist and it doesn't"

What do you mean it doesn't?  You just said it did!

Comment: Haha, oh wow.. /facepalm you're right! That mistake actually helped me solve a problem too :)

Comment: Am i correct in assuming if it fails for any one instance, the whole relation is not transitive?

For Example. 
{(1,3),(1, 2),(2, 3),(2, 4)}

Comment: A relation is transitive if, *whenever* a~b and b~c, we have a~c.  So this is non-transitive because 1~2 and 2~4 but we do not have 1~4.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)